# Jenkins: how could I access Generic Webhook Trigger Parameters from Pipeline script from SCM

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-generic-webhook-trigger

I setup the pipeline which has

- General Webhook Trigger: I added the variable of Post content parameters like this:

[image: build triggers]

- Declarative pipeline script: this script *resided in Bitbucket repository*:

```
@Library("pipeline-shared-lib")_
buildPipeline ([
    GIT_TARGET_BRANCH : "origin/${BRANCH_NAME}",
    GIT_CREDENTIAL_ID : 'xxx',
    GIT_REMOTE_URL: "${REPOSITORY_URL}.git",
    DOCKER_REGISTRY : 'xxx',
    CLEAR_DOCKER_IMAGES : false,
    VERSION_PATH : 'xxx',
    TEAM_WEB_HOOK_URL : "xxx"
])
```

My problem is when I built this pipe line I faced the error `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: BRANCH_NAME for class: groovy.lang.Binding`. Please noted that this script ran fine when it was in Jenkins textarea before I moved it to Bitbucket repository. Please give me any clue, I appreciate for all helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, this is my own mistake.

The error was occurred by running the job manually <kbd>Build Now</kbd> button. So, the trigger was not invoked `BRANCH_NAME` parameter consequently was undefined. )-: